# Assistance with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings.

Example:

- 12 CG GRB
- 6GRC 11.2 MK
- 2 GR 1.75LRG

And I would like to break them to the following group

- [12,CG] [GRB]
- [6,GRC] [11.2,MK]
- [2,GR] [1.75,LRG]

I'm using this regex - (\d+.?\d*).*?([A-Z]+) but with it, I'm unable to capture the first example correctly. Instead of [12,CG] [GRB], i get [12,CG].

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\d+\.?\d*).*?([A-Z]+)')
test_str = u"12 CG GRB"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Please post your code along with the question

Comment: Your examples are too few,  looking at them, I can suggest `(\d*\.?\d+)?\s*([A-Z]+)`, but this might match more than necessary.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the `.*?` with a `\s*` to match zero or more whitespasces, and make the first capture group optional:

```
(\d*\.?\d+)?\s*([A-Z]+)
           ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK3tL1/1).

Note I also modified the number matching subpattern to `\d*\.?\d+` to also mathc numbers like `.56`. You may keep your own pattern for that.

*Pattern details*:

- `(\d*\.?\d+)?` - Optional group 1 capturing

  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 2 capturing one or more uppercase ASCII letters.

To get the capture group contents as a list of tuples, use a `re.findall` ([demo](http://ideone.com/NVwFPN)):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\d*\.?\d+)?\s*([A-Z]+)')
s = "12 CG GRB\n6GRC 11.2 MK\n2 GR 1.75LRG"
print(p.findall(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "12 CG GRB\n6GRC 11.2 MK\n2 GR 1.75LRG"
re.split(r"(?<!\d)\s", s)
```

The output is:

```
['12 CG', 'GRB', '6GRC', '11.2 MK', '2 GR', '1.75LRG']
```

Comment: Add some words of explanation please. The idea is to help the OP, not write their code for them.